# Django gunicorn access denied error

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I've setup an application to run with gunicorn on nginx. Here's my gunicorn's setup:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="davidbien"                                  
DJANGODIR=/home/ec2-user/davidbien             
SOCKFILE=/home/ec2-user/davidbien/davidbien.sock  
USER=ec2-user                                       
GROUP=ec2-user                                     
NUM_WORKERS=3                                     
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=davidbien.settings             
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=davidbien.wsgi                    

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../virtual/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves
exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
--name $NAME \
--workers $NUM_WORKERS \
--user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
--bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
--log-level=debug \
--log-file=-
```

Here's my nginx setup:

```
upstream app_server_djangoapp {
server   unix:/home/ec2-user/davidbien/davidbien.sock fail_timeout=0;
 }

server {
listen 80;
server_name ;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/guni-access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/guni-error.log info;

keepalive_timeout 52.56.193.57;

# path for static files
root /home/ec2-user/davidbien/davidbien/static;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://app_server_djangoapp;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

When running nginx I keep getting the following error in the logs:

```
[crit] 23465#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/ec2-user/davidbien/davidbien.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 2.96.149.96, server: 52.56.193.57, request: "GET /faviconn.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ec2-user/davidbien/davidbieen.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "52.56.193.57", referrer: "http://52.56.193.57/"
```

What is wrong with this? I believe the user I'm using is the owner of the folders inside its own directory.

Comment: But does the nginx user have access to those directories? Better to put the sock file somewhere else.

Comment: I ran sudo chmod -R 755 /home/ec2-user/davidbien. SHouldn't that give any user access to that folder?

Comment: Ok, now I get that the file or directory does not exist. What do I do?